# What is the fastest classical simulator for quantum circuits with only Clifford gates?

Tags: simulation, quantum-circuit, clifford-group

What is the fastest classical simulator for quantum circuits with only Clifford Gates?

And is there any "friendly" implementation e.g. in Python (or in some well-known libraries like Qiskit)?

Fast simulators for quantum circuits with other constraints are also well accepted.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'fast'? Do you mean _efficient_ in a theoretical sense? Or an actually 'fast' implementation by whatever measure? If the latter, I suspect that anything in Python could considered as not fast.

Comment: Also, there's [this](https://www.scottaaronson.com/chp/) simulator by Aaronson and Gottesman written in C which is generally quite fast.

Comment: I found [Stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/glue/python/README.md) , and it seems to be great for my purpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the current fastest simulator for stabilizer circuits is my simulator Stim ([source code on github](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim), [paper in Quantum](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-07-06-497/), [python package on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/stim/)). This is especially  true if you're doing bulk sampling:

[image: stim go fast]

Note the Y axis; that's a log-log plot.

There are some simulators that are faster in specialized circumstances, e.g. for piecewise separable circuits or for constant-depth 2d circuits. But probably Stim will meet your speed needs.